# compute determinant of complex matrix fortran90

Tags: matrix, fortran, intel-fortran

I need to compute the determinant of complex matrix which is symmetric. Size of matrix ranges from 500*500 to 2000*2000. Is there any subroutine for me to call? By the way, I use ifort to compile.

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to calculate the determinant? Most probably you want a related quantity such as the condition number. Several relevant routines exist within LAPACK (this is included in intel's MKL library which you may have if you have ifort). According to the LAPACK FAQ, there are stability problems with using determinants http://www.netlib.org/lapack/faq.html#_are_there_routines_in_lapack_to_compute_determinants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do an LU-decomposition [as described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205427/determinant-of-a-big-matrix). I would suggest using [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) for this task...

This [article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/matrix-determinant-with-the-lapack-routine-dspsv/) has some code in `C` doing that for a real-valued symmetric matrix, so you need to exchange `dspsv` by `zspsv` to handle double-precision complex matrices.